# Celery tasks without result write to result backend

Tags: celery, django-celery

I have some tasks which should return result, and some tasks that don't.
I want to force tasks which shouldn't return result not to write anything in result backend (for example None). How can I achieve that in Celery?

For example it's my tasks:

```
@app.task
def taskWithResult():
    # ...code...
    return res

@app.task
def taskWithNoResult():
    # ...code without return...
```

---

And also I have special queue for some others task which also don't return any result, can I mark that queue as with tasks which mustn't write in result backend?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From celery document you can set ignore result flag to True.
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html?highlight=default_retry_delay#celery.app.task.Task.ignore_result

For example:

```
@app.task(ignore_result=True)
def taskWithNoResult():
    # ...code without return..
```

Comment: You can use apply_async to choose the queue for task.

[link](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html?highlight=apply_async#routing-options)

Answer (score 7):

### Global Config

```
app.conf.task_ignore_result = True
```

### Locally close return task results:

```
@app.task(ignore_result=True)
def add(...):
```

If you only want to return and persist the abnormal results of the task execution failure for subsequent investigation and analysis, then you can apply the following configuration while using the database as a Result Backend:

### Only store task errors in the result backend.

```
app.conf.task_ignore_result = True
app.conf.task_store_errors_even_if_ignored = True
```

Comment: It's worth nothing this can be applied on specific tasks, e.g:
@task(name="test")
def test(ignore_result=True, store_errors_even_if_ignored=True):

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do this conditionally, you can use `setattr(self.request, "ignore_result", True)`

```
@shared_task(bind=True)
def run_process(self):
try:
    processor = Processor(strategy_token)
    completed = execute_strategy()
    if not completed:
        setattr(self.request, "ignore_result", True)
except Exception as error:
    logger.exception(error)
```